# “Error: unable to access jar file” pops up every minute in Java

Tags: java

This annoying message keeps popping up, every minute, and it's driving my crazing, I tried rebooting, and reinstalling java.

Java Virtual Machine Launcher

```
Error: unable to access jar file
C:\ Users\ (my username)\ AppData\ Local\ Temp\ ..\ Microsoft\ ExplorerSync.db
```

[image: Window Java Message]

Comment: Do you have any antivirus software?

Comment: This does not appear to be related to Java development and may be better suited to SuperUser.com. You'll need to do some troubleshooting to find out which process/application is producing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation yet to comment. However, this happened to me today. Looks like the file was there for a while. After further investigation, it looks like it was a virus. Decompiling it returned a small java program that downloaded it's payload from an obscure website and does some filesystem stuff. For further investigation this is it's virustotal hash: 955904c82e953113183aad6a60fef962847549d02f531a62bf00d724c3c482c3

I recommend you delete it immediately.