# How to get rid of Java Virtual Machine Launcher error?

Tags: virtual-machine, java, eclipse

Today I've installed Java 8, beacuse I decided to make Java applications. I downloaded Eclipse 2021 and set all configurations. Everything works fine except of poping up dialogbox with problem "Error: Unable to access jarfile (path)\ExplorerSync.db". If I close the box, it appears 1 minute later. I wanted to learn Java, but I see it doesn't let me do it :) I've tried to reinstall Java, and when it's gone, it doesn't appear, but after installation of Java, it begins to appear. Does someone know how to help me? Image of problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDSFJ.png)

Comment: This appears [to be a duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1376380/error-unable-to-access-jar-file-pops-up-every-minute-in-java).  The only answer implies that it is a virus inserted into one of your dl packages.  Are you SURE that you have a legit source you got all of this from?  The reason I accept this point of view is that it is trying to load something with a stupid path with an extension of DB when it *should be* JAR.  This is a total virus programmer d**k move.  I might not be right.. but I am guessing that I am.

Comment: Also, Microsoft would ***never*** store a file like that at that hierarchy in the file tree.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply